# ServiceBusError : Handler failed: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get_token'

Tags: python, azureservicebus

Im getting the below error when i run my code. This code is to requeue the Deadletter messages.

Error:

```
Exception has occurred: ServiceBusError
Handler failed: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get_token'.
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get_token'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
  File "C:\Users\asisaacr\Downloads\project work\DeadletterRequeue\requeue.py", line 39, in <module>
    with from_subscription_receiver:
azure.servicebus.exceptions.ServiceBusError: Handler failed: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get_token'.
```

Code :

```
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage
import json
import configparser

# Read configuration from config.conf file
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.conf')

service_namespace = config.get('svcbus', 'service_namespace')
shared_access_key_name = config.get('svcbus', 'shared_access_key_name')
shared_access_key_value = config.get('svcbus', 'shared_access_key')
from_subscription_name = config.get('svcbus', 'from_subscription_name')
to_topic_name = config.get('svcbus', 'to_topic_name')
batch_size = int(config.get('svcbus', 'Batch'))

# Create a ServiceBusClient with the shared access key credential for the source subscription
bus_service_source = ServiceBusClient(
    fully_qualified_namespace=service_namespace,
    credential=(shared_access_key_name, shared_access_key_value)
)

# Create a ServiceBusClient with the shared access key credential for the destination topic
bus_service_destination = ServiceBusClient(
    fully_qualified_namespace=service_namespace,
    credential=(shared_access_key_name, shared_access_key_value)
)

# Get a sender for the destination topic
to_topic_sender = bus_service_destination.get_topic_sender(to_topic_name)

# Get a receiver for the source subscription's dead letter queue
from_subscription_receiver = bus_service_source.get_subscription_receiver(
    topic_name=to_topic_name,
    subscription_name=from_subscription_name
)

counter = 0

with from_subscription_receiver:
    for message in from_subscription_receiver.peek_messages(max_message_count=batch_size):
        print(f"Reading dead letter from {from_subscription_name}:")
        request = json.loads(str(message))
        props = message.user_properties

        if b"DeadLetterReason" in props:
            del props[b"DeadLetterReason"]

        if b"DeadLetterErrorDescription" in props:
            del props[b"DeadLetterErrorDescription"]

        msg = ServiceBusMessage(json.dumps(request))
        msg.user_properties = props

        to_topic_sender.send_messages(msg)

        print(f"...message removed after being added to topic: {to_topic_name}  {counter}")
        message.complete()
        counter += 1

        if counter == batch_size:
            break

# Close the ServiceBusClients
bus_service_source.close()
bus_service_destination.close()
```

I havent tried anything, I need help inorder to fix this

Comment: In which statement do you get the error? I can see that you use the [ServiceBusClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-servicebus/azure.servicebus.servicebusclient?view=azure-python) class but I was not able to see where it fails.

Comment: line 39, in <module>
    with from_subscription_receiver:

Comment: The `ServiceBusClient` constructor's `credential` parameter accepts only the `TokenCredential`, `AzureSasCredential` and `AzureNamedKeyCredential` object. But you provided a tuple of a shared access key and value.

Comment: @Ashwin Roy adding to the point of `ServiceBusClient`  
Péter Szilvási 
    ```connection_string = f'Endpoint=sb://{service_namespace}.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName={shared_access_key_name};SharedAccessKey={shared_access_key_value}'

# Create a ServiceBusClient using the connection string
servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)```

Comment: I tried this  [code](https://i.imgur.com/ylcVzxM.png)  [Output](https://i.imgur.com/pv4UJ6w.png)

Comment: ```pip install --upgrade azure-servicebus```

Answer (score 0):

The error might occur due to the improper usage of the `ServiceBusClient` and the credentials provided.

- The code below reads messages from a dead letter queue (DLQ) for a subscription to a topic in Azure Service Bus. It removes the DLQ-related properties from the messages, sends them to the topic, and handles invalid JSON format [messages](https://i.imgur.com/1F0QgPG.png).
- I used `ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string` to create a `ServiceBusClient` instance with a connection string.
- I added decoding the message body explicitly using `message_body.decode('utf-8')` before attempting to load it as JSON, and a `try`/`except` block to catch `JSONDecodeError`.
- I configured basic logging with `logging.basicConfig` and used `logging.info` and `logging.error` to log informational and error messages.
- I referred to this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-python-how-to-use-queues?tabs=passwordless) for Azure Service Bus with Python.

**Code:**

```py
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage, ServiceBusReceiveMode
import json
import configparser

# Read configuration from config.conf file
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.conf')

service_namespace = config.get('svcbus', 'service_namespace')
shared_access_key_name = config.get('svcbus', 'shared_access_key_name')
shared_access_key_value = config.get('svcbus', 'shared_access_key')
from_subscription_name = config.get('svcbus', 'from_subscription_name')
to_topic_name = config.get('svcbus', 'to_topic_name')
batch_size = int(config.get('svcbus', 'Batch'))

# Build the connection string
connection_string = f'Endpoint=sb://{service_namespace}.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName={shared_access_key_name};SharedAccessKey={shared_access_key_value}'

# Create a ServiceBusClient using the connection string
servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

# Get a sender for the destination topic
to_topic_sender = servicebus_client.get_topic_sender(to_topic_name)

# Get a receiver for the source subscription's dead letter queue in PEEK_LOCK mode
from_subscription_receiver = servicebus_client.get_subscription_receiver(
    topic_name=to_topic_name,
    subscription_name=from_subscription_name,
    receive_mode=ServiceBusReceiveMode.PEEK_LOCK,
    max_wait_time=5  # Adjust max_wait_time as needed
)

counter = 0

with from_subscription_receiver:
    for message in from_subscription_receiver.receive_messages(max_message_count=batch_size):
        print(f"Reading dead letter from {from_subscription_name}:")

        message_content_type = message.content_type

        if message_content_type == "application/json":
            try:
                message_body = b''.join(list(message.body))
                request = json.loads(message_body.decode('utf-8'))
                
                # Print the message content
                print(f"Message Content: {request}")
                print(f"Message Body: {message_body}")

                props = message.application_properties

                if b"DeadLetterReason" in props:
                    del props[b"DeadLetterReason"]

                if b"DeadLetterErrorDescription" in props:
                    del props[b"DeadLetterErrorDescription"]

                msg = ServiceBusMessage(json.dumps(request))
                msg.application_properties = props

                to_topic_sender.send_messages(msg)

                print(f"...message removed after being added to topic: {to_topic_name}  {counter}")
                from_subscription_receiver.complete_message(message)  # Complete the message
                counter += 1
            except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
                # Handle invalid JSON format
                print(f"Error parsing message: {e}")
        
        if counter == batch_size:
            break

# Close the ServiceBusClient
servicebus_client.close()
```

**Output:**

[image]

- Refer to this link for `azure-identity` with Python in Azure Service [Bus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-python-how-to-use-queues?tabs=passwordless#use-pip-to-install-packages).