# Azure Function Timer Trigger: Timeout Error When Accessing and Dequeuing Queue in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues

I have an Azure Function that is triggered by a timer every 5 minutes. This function is designed to access and dequeue messages from an Azure Service Bus Queue. However, I'm encountering a timeout error when the function attempts to dequeue messages, and I'm having trouble resolving it.

```
\\ function.json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 */5 * * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
\\ index.js

const { ServiceBusClient } = require("@azure/service-bus");

module.exports = async function (context, myTimer) {
  try {
    var timeStamp = new Date().toISOString();
    const serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient(
      "myConnectionString"
    );

    const receiver = serviceBusClient.createReceiver("contacts", {
      receiveMode: "receiveAndDelete",
    });

    for await (let message of receiver.getMessageIterator()) {
      // your code here
      context.log(message);
    }
    context.log("Timer function processed request at", timeStamp);
  } catch (error) {
    context.log.error(error);
    context.res = {
      status: 500,
      body: "Internal Server Error",
    };
  }
};
```

The issue I'm facing is that the function times out when trying to access the queue and dequeue messages, especially if there are many messages in the queue. I suspect that the function may not be completing within the timeout window.

What can I do to address this timeout issue and ensure my Azure Function successfully processes messages from the queue every 5 minutes? Are there any optimizations or best practices that I should be following to handle potential timeout scenarios?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Timer trigger, and then you call it Service Bus Queue trigger - decide what you want !? Timer trigger runs every X minutes or whatever your CRON expression is.  Instead, write a function that "acts" one one message at a time, and bind that to Service Bus Queue trigger. if there are many messages, then that many "instances" of your function will be executed by the Azure Function runtime. Hope you get it.

Comment: See the Service Bus `Queue trigger` example from Microsoft Azure documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-javascript#example)

Comment: Hi @AnandSowmithiran, I didn’t want the Service Bus Queue to be the trigger. I’m trying to minimize costs so I would prefer to have a periodic check, rather than checking every time I get a new message.

Comment: If you want to handle them periodically in batches, then follow these [best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements?tabs=net-standard-sdk-2) - though they are written for C# client sdk, those options are present in `javascript client` Az SB library too.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason for the issue you are facing is that the function times out when trying to access the queue and dequeue messages, especially if there are many messages in the queue. One way to address this timeout issue and ensure your Azure function successfully processes messages from the queue every 5 minutes and process messages in batches from the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77407835/servicebuserror-handler-failed-tuple-object-has-no-attribute-get-token/77420782#77420782).
The below code provides an Azure Functions timer trigger that uses the Azure Service Bus to receive and process messages from a Service Bus queue.

- The `maxMessagesToProcess` variable indicates the maximum number of messages to process in a single execution of the function.

```js
const { ServiceBusClient } = require("@azure/service-bus");

module.exports = async function (context, myTimer) {
  try {
    var timeStamp = new Date().toISOString();
    const serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient(
      "Azure Service Bus connection String "
    );

    const receiver = serviceBusClient.createReceiver("Azure ServiceBus Queue Name", {
      receiveMode: "receiveAndDelete",
    });

    const maxMessagesToProcess = 1; // Adjust this value as needed

    for (let i = 0; i < maxMessagesToProcess; i++) {
      try {
        const messages = await receiver.receiveMessages(1);
        if (messages.length === 0) {
          // No more messages to process, break the loop
          break;
        }
      
        const message = messages[0];
        const messageBody = message.body.toString('utf8'); // Convert the buffer to a string

        // Process the message content here

        // Log the message content as a string
        context.log(messageBody);
      } catch (messageError) {
        // Handle the error when receiving or processing a message
        context.log.error("Error receiving/processing a message:", messageError);
        // You can choose to continue processing other messages or return an error response if needed
      }
    }

    context.log("Timer function processed request at", timeStamp);
  } catch (error) {
    context.log.error("Error in the main function:", error);
    context.res = {
      status: 500,
      body: "Internal Server Error",
    };
  }
};
```

**Output:**
[image]

[image]

**Multiple messages at the same time:**
[image]